# Animação CSS3 não executar quando carregar a página

Tags: css3, animação

Tenho o seguinte código:

```css
body{margin:0; padding:0; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;}
aside{
    width: 200px;
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
}
ul{
    display:block;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li{
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
a{
    display:block;
    padding:4px 8px;
    color:#999999;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes asidemenuitembg {
    from {background-color: #F0F0F0; color: #999999;}
    to {background-color: #0C6FA6; color: #F0F0F0;}
}
@keyframes asidemenuitembg {
    from {background-color: #F0F0F0; color: #999999;}
    to {background-color: #0C6FA6; color: #F0F0F0;}
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes asidemenuitembgr {
    from {background-color: #0C6FA6; color: #F0F0F0;}
    to {background-color: #F0F0F0; color: #999999;}
}
@keyframes asidemenuitembgr {
    from {background-color: #0C6FA6; color: #F0F0F0;}
    to {background-color: #F0F0F0; color: #999999;}
}

aside a{
    -webkit-animation: asidemenuitembgr .4s ease-out;
    -o-animation: asidemenuitembgr .4s ease-out;
    animation: asidemenuitembgr .4s ease-out;
}

aside a:hover{
    color: #F0F0F0;
    background-color: #0C6FA6;
    -webkit-animation: asidemenuitembg .6s ease-in;
    -o-animation: asidemenuitembg .6s ease-in;
    animation: asidemenuitembg .6s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<aside>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Repare que na execução do *script* a animação é executada, no caso essa animação que é executada é a animação de quando o cursor sai de sobre o elemento (evento *mouse out*). Como fazer para que essa animação não seja executada quando a página é carregada, ou qual a maneira correta de fazer a animação *mouse out* com CSS3?

<sub>**Obs.:** Eu tentei adicionar uma classe `loading` no elemento `aside` e nega-lo no seletor CSS `:not(.loading) a:hover`, porém quando a classe é removida a animação é executada.</sub>

Comment: Como seu elemento sofre uma única mudança (muda a cor e volta pro estado normal) o melhor é utilizar `transition` como fez. Mas só deixando aqui uma informação que, você pode parar uma animação definindo `animation-play-state: paused;` e pode fazê-la funcionar novamente com `animation-play-state: running` [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-play-state.asp). Mas é inviável trocar essas regras a cada `:hover` no elemento. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolvi o problema utilizando `transition` no em vez de `animation`.

```css
body{margin:0; padding:0; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;}
aside{
    width: 200px;
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
}
ul{
    display:block;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li{
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
a{
    display:block;
    padding:4px 8px;
    color:#999999;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
}


aside a{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

aside a:hover{
    color: #F0F0F0;
    background-color: #0C6FA6;
}
```

```html
<aside>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```